# Combining two JSON files

Tags: javascript, arrays

Right now I am feeding in the contents of one JSON feed and display

```
(function () {


    var twitterLikes = "data.json";

    //Grab the JSON
    $.getJSON(twitterLikes, {
        format: "json"
    })

    .done(function (data) {

        //iterate through each item
        $.each(data.likes, function (i, likes) {

            //Print out JSON results
            var twitterLike = '<div class="twitterLike" id="' + likes.id + '"><img class="twitterLikeImage" src="' + likes.image + '"><p class="twitterLikeCaption">' + likes.caption + '</p><a class="twitterLikeLink" href="' + likes.link + '" target="_blank">See original post</a></div>';

            //Append printed reuslts to parent container
            document.getElementById("twitterLikes").innerHTML += twitterLike;

            //Cap the results
            if (i === 12) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

This needs modification.  I have another JSON file that I've created as some sort of "Locked" file, which basically locks a particular post in a given position.

```
{ "locked":[{"id":90210, "position":3}] }
```

How would I modify my function to parse the 2nd JSON File (locked).  Basically look in the locked file, see if theres an id and position.  Match that id to the 1st JSON file (data.json).  Lock that post based on id to the particular position.  Go through data.json and paint the rest of the posts skipping the locked positions.  Should only show 12 at most also.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar how to combine two json feeds.

Comment: Can I use .extend?  But how would I lock in the position?

Comment: It sounds like you don't need to "combine" the JSON files. Read the lock file and store it in memory, then as you iterate through the twitterLikes JSON, check the in-memory lock file

Comment: I think to start you want to have both .json objects to hand. For this you could nest two async `$.getJSON` calls. Then once you have both data objects the problem is greatly simplified. Underscore/ LoDash would be useful to help quickly map arrays of id's and positions. But I don't really understand the substitution model that you require. Not sure if this helps!

Comment: Anyone got a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your locking mechanism, but some variant on (I have used lodash to help - but it's not necessary)

```
$.getJSON("data.json", { format: "json" })
.done(function (data) {

    $.getJSON("locked.json", {format: "json"})
    .done(function(locked){

        var lockedIds = _.map(locked, function(l){
            return l.id
        })

        $.each(data.likes, function(i, likes){

            // If not locked then process
            if (!_.contains(likes.id, lockedIds)){
                // do something here
            }

        })

    })

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  This is what I got so far:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joe.  This is what I got so far:
    $.getJSON("data.json", { format: "json" })

```
.done(function( data ) {
$.getJSON("locked.json", {format: "json"})
.done(function(locked){

var lockedIds = _.map(locked, function(l){
return l.id
})

//iterate through each item
$.each( data.likes, function( i, likes ) {
if (!_.contains(likes.id, lockedIds)){

//Print out JSON results
var twitterLike='<div class="twitterLike" id="'+likes.id+'"><img class="twitterLikeImage" src="'+likes.image+'"><p class="twitterLikeCaption">'+likes.caption+'</p><a class="twitterLikeLink" href="'+likes.link+'" target="_blank">See original post</a></div>';

//Append printed reuslts to parent container
document.getElementById("twitterLikes").innerHTML+=twitterLike;
}
//Cap the results
if ( i === 12 ) {
return false;
}
});
});
})();
```

I seem to be off a little bit.  You are right, I don't necessarily need to combine the two.  More need to display those posts in a "locked" position, then move onto the rest from the original feed.

**DATA.JSON**

```
    {
    "count": 2,
    "likes": [
        {
            "link": "http://twitter.com/p/tQc2YNh3ox/",
            "caption": "Yada",
            "profile_pic": "",
            "likes": 27,
            "id": "815278414704900657_1364335477",
            "image": "http://twitter.com/pic1.png"
        }, {
            "link": "http://twitter.com/p/tQc2YNh3ox2/",
            "caption": "Yada2",
            "profile_pic": "",
            "likes": 27,
            "id": "815078520979421610_1364335477",
            "image": "http://twitter.com/pic2.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

**LOCKED.JSON**

```
 {
    "likes": [
        {
            "id": "815278414704900657_1364335477",
            "position": 3
        }, {
            "id": "815078520979421610_1364335477",
            "position": 5
        }
    ]
}
```